# Como fazer o webscrapping de um site que tem método post?

Tags: r, post, web-scraping

Estou com problema em fazer o `webscrapping` para sites que utilizam o  método `post`, por exemplo, preciso extrair todas as notícias relacionadas à partidos políticos do site: http://www.diariodemarilia.com.br.

Segue abaixo uma programação que eu fiz de um jornal que utiliza o método `get` para mostrar qual é meu objetivo com esta programação.

```
# iniciar bibliotecas 
library(XML)
library(xlsx)
# URL real = http://www.imparcial.com.br/site/page/2?s=%28PSDB%29


url_base <-"http://www.imparcial.com.br/site/page/koxa?s=%28quatro%29"

url_base <- gsub("quatro", "PSD", url_base)

link_imparcial <- c()

for (i in 1:4){

  print(i)

  url1 <- gsub("koxa", i, url_base)

  pag<- readLines(url1)

  pag<- htmlParse(pag)

  pag<- xmlRoot(pag)

  links <- xpathSApply(pag, "//h1[@class='cat-titulo']/a", xmlGetAttr, name="href")

link_imparcial <- c(link_imparcial, links)
}
dados <- data.frame()

for(links in link_imparcial){

pag1<- readLines (links)

pag1<- htmlParse(pag1)

pag1<- xmlRoot(pag1)

titulo <- xpathSApply (pag1, "//div[@class='titulo']/h1", xmlValue)

data_hora <-xpathSApply (pag1, "//span[@class='data-post']", xmlValue)

texto <- xpathSApply (pag1, "//div[@class='conteudo']/p", xmlValue)

dados <- rbind(dados, data.frame(titulo, data_hora, texto))
}


agregar <- 

aggregate(dados$texto,list(dados$titulo,dados$data_hora),paste,collapse=' ')


#definir diretorio

setwd("C:\\Users\\8601314\\Documents")

# salvar em xlsx
write.xlsx(agregar, "PSDB.xlsx", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Se não for possível resolver meu problema, gostaria de indicações onde eu posso encontrar exemplos de programação com o método `post`.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPt. Adicione código na pergunta, não uma imagem dele, isso dificulta analisar e reproduzir o problema. Sugiro a leitura de [ask]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nesse caso você pode fazer assim usando o pacote `httr`:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

url <- "http://www.diariodemarilia.com.br/resultado/"
res <- POST(url, body = list("Busca" = "PT"))
```

Depois disso pode extrair os dados da forma usual ou usando o `rvest`:

```
noticias <- content(res, as = "text", encoding = "latin1") %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes("td") 


# extrai titulos
noticias %>%
  html_nodes("strong") %>%
  html_text()
# extrai links
noticias %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  keep(~str_detect(.x, fixed("/noticia/")))
# extrai data
noticias %>%
  html_nodes("em") %>%
  html_text()
```

---

A idéia para extrair informações quando o site recebe formulários `POST` é descobrir quais são as informações que o site envia para o servidor.

Eu sempre abro o site usando o `Chrome` aperto `F12` para abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e vou p/ a aba `Network`.

Em seguida envio o formulário normalmente pelo site e volto p/ a aba  `Network`, e clico no primeiro item da lista, neste caso é `/resultado/`.

Agora, veja lá embaixo na imagem a parte **Form Data**, são essas informações que você precisa enviar para o servidor usando o parâmetro `body` da função `POST` do `httr`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito boa essa dica de olhar meu Chrome os dados do form, eu não sabia e sempre ia só pelo HTML.